# How to use(put) sprintf to char pointer? C

Tags: c, pointers, printf

Is it possible to put(or copy) sprintf output to pointer? How?

Like this?

```
double myNumber = 88.123;
char *pointer;

sprintf(pointer, myNumber);
```

Comment: A web search will show you any number of examples of how to use `sprintf`...

Comment: use `%lf` print format and see [cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/)

Comment: @amdixon: No need for `l`...

Comment: Can you send me a link where is work in pointer? I did not find. And if you're bored go to read the paper, and do not write useless advice.

Comment: @amdixon: its char array, not a pointer

Comment: An array decays into a pointer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you read the [manual for sprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/), you would find that the arguments for it are:

```
int sprintf(char *str, const char *format, ...);
```

Where `str` is a pointer containing the address of where you want the output to be saved and the rest of the arguments being identical to printf.

In your case, you'd want:

```
double myNumber = 88.123;
char *pointer = hopefully_something_with_enough_space;

sprintf(pointer, "%f", myNumber);
```

Answer (score 1):

`sprintf` prints into a character buffer. You can use malloc to dynamically allocate memory and store a pointer to that memory in `pointer`. After that you use `sprintf` just like you would with static character array.

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocation some memory for `pointer`. Also read the manual page for `sprintf`. You are missing the format parameter